# Post Parameters are not sent to PHP from ajax request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, http-post

My Request

```
jQuery.ajax({               
                url: 'PHPdocs/appsearch.php',
                data: {term:'blub'},
                type: "POST",
                async: true,
                data: "text",
                success: function(msg){
                    $('div[data-role="content"]').append(msg);
                    },
                error: function(msg){}})
```

my PHP File

```
$json = file_get_contents("https://itunes.apple.com/search?country=de&entity=software& 
term=".$_POST['term'];);
$results = json_decode($json, true);
echo $json;
```

What i Get as result

```
Notice: Undefined index: term in C:\xampp1\htdocs\AppRain\PHPdocs\appsearch.php on line 3
{ "resultCount":0, "results": [] }
```

I need to sent the term to search from my jscode to the php file via Post but everything i tried did not work.

I also triedto set type to GET so that it ist a Get request but the Ajax did not work. But when i used get i could use it with the URL apprain.php?term=.... without i only copied it to the url field from the browser. It seems that every parameter sent over $.ajax or jQuery.ajax is blocked Please can someone help me.

Comment: ok found the problem i typed data instead of datatype

Answer (score 1):

You are overwriting you `data` key:

```
data: "text",
```

You should remove that line.

Comment: I think you meant to use "dataType" on that line so your script expects text back.  You can skip that line altogether too. Text is the default.